# How to send toggle switch data from PHP to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have an HTML, JavaScript and PHP code on the same page working together. I want to send 0 or 1 to a JSON file on change of a toggle switch. I think I'm almost there but when I reload the page after switching the toggle it goes back to 0.

Here is my code

```
$message = '';
$error = '';
$isChecked = $_POST["status"];

if(file_exists('orders.json'))
{
  $current_data = file_get_contents('orders.json');
  $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
  if($isChecked) {
    $status = 1;
  }else{
    $status = 0;
  }
  $extra = array('ordersOpen' =>  $status);
  $final_data = json_encode($extra);
  if(file_put_contents('orders.json', $final_data)){
    $message = "<label class='text-success'>File Appended Success fully</p>";
  }
}else{
  $error = 'JSON File not exits';
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON('/orders.json', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        checkbox1.checked = data.ordersOpen
      });

      $('.status').on('change', function() {
      var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
      var selectedData;
      var $switchLabel = $('.switch-label');
      console.log('isChecked: ' + isChecked);
      if(isChecked) {
         $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"/sendnotification.php",
                data:{status:true},
                success:function(result){
                  console.log("Submitted");
                }
                });
        } else {
          $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"/sendnotification.php",
                 data:{status:false},
                 success:function(result){
                   console.log("Submitted");
                 }
                 });
        }
    });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 34px;
    }

    .switch input {
      display: none;
    }

    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ca2222;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }

    .slider.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }

    .slider.round:before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 26px;
      width: 26px;
      left: 4px;
      bottom: 4px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }

    input:checked+.slider {
      background-color: #2ab934;
    }

    input:focus+.slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }

    input:checked+.slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(68px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(68px);
      transform: translateX(68px);
    }

    .on {
      display: none;
    }

    .on,
    .off {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    input:checked+.slider .on {
      display: block;
    }

    input:checked+.slider .off {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="postnotification.php" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Title: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Massage: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massage"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

  <p> Do you want to close orders from apps?
    <div id="bit00_3">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="status">
        <div class="slider round">
          <span class="on">Open</span>
          <span class="off">Closed</span>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>

  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I basically want to change an "ordersOpen" property in JSON when the toggle switch changes and even if I reload the page the switch should show based on the last change made in JSON.
This is my JSON. I want the value of ordersOpen to change everytime I toggle the switch.

```
{"ordersOpen":0}
```

Comment: You mean you want the checkbox `<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="status">` to be checked/unchecked based on the JSON value of `ordersOpen`?

Comment: Exactly! Also, change the JSON value of ordersOpen on the change of toggle.

Comment: do you have two php file or one ? and do you want change `<label>` tag purely using ajax ?

Comment: @DickensAS   have one separate PHP file to submit the form data. But to change the JSON content in another file I am using PHP in the same file. It doesn't matter what I use I just want the JSON to be changed with respect to the Toggle switch.

Comment: given my answer, I put `return` reason being am using single php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate AJAX you can simply use `echo` and only few words which can be received via AJAX resposne

Try this code, I tested this code using XAMPP in my local, AJAX getting cached for `$.getJSON` therefore I did hard relead to see the difference

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["status"]) && isset($_POST["ajax"])) {
    $isChecked = ("".$_POST["status"]=="true");

    if(file_exists('orders.json'))
    {
      $current_data = file_get_contents('orders.json');
      $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
      if($isChecked) {
        $status = 1;
      }else{
        $status = 0;
      }
      $extra = array('ordersOpen' =>  $status);
      $final_data = json_encode($extra);
      if(file_put_contents('orders.json', $final_data)){
        echo "File Appended Success fully";
      }
    }else{
      echo "JSON File not exits";
    }
    return;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tested the code but it doesn't seem to be working with your version. My code used to change the value of JSON to 1 the first time I toggle the switch but goes back to 0 once I reload the page.

Comment: which means your code is different, I tested this code by pasting the entire code in single file `sendnotification.php` and I loaded in browser as `http://localhost:8088/sendnotification.php` I saw it perfectly working

Comment: I put the code here you can test it https://pastebin.com/kuMRSFUt, you only need two file, one this file as `sendnotification.php` and `orders.json` in the same directory in the apache server

Comment: I have tested it with your code in pastebin but still it's the same. You can check with these links, I am using your code currently: https://speedypeppermalton.co.uk/fcm/sendnotification.php and https://speedypeppermalton.co.uk/fcm/orders.json

Comment: You can see that once I toggle the switch to open and reload the website it goes back to close and it doesn't stay open as it supposed to

Comment: no no, it is a cache issue, press Ctrl+Shift+I and hard reload the page

Comment: your https://speedypeppermalton.co.uk/orders.json is not working, do you have a file ?

Comment: speedypeppermalton.co.uk/fcm/orders.json This is the correct url

Comment: please change this code `$.getJSON('/orders.json'` to `$.getJSON('/fcm/orders.json'`, you also need to change your PHP code for that file location, that file should not be write protected

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of possible solutions. You need to check $_POST['status'] value to set checkbox state.

If your ajax script works well, it's enough to change one line:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="status" <?php if (isset($_POST['status']))  echo (($_POST['status'] == true) ? 'checked' : ''); ?>>
```

Comment: I changed that one line but it doesn't seem to work.